# Terminology for topologies that can't be embedded in a plane (without severing the topology)?

Tags: terminology, geometric-topology

In some code I've written, I justify the existence of a certain structure as follows:

> X is needed because we support topologies that cannot result in a planar embedding, e.g.
>   cube, sphere, torus, cylinder, Möbius strip.

Another alternative is

> X is needed because we support geometries whose topologies are not equivalent / homeomorphic to a finite plane.

Any more accurate ways to put this? It would be nice to have a single go-to word for this concept, e.g.

> X is needed because of the existence of *blartigons*.

Comment: Your two highlighted bits aren't equivalent, nor is the first one correct. All the spaces you mention can be "mapped to the plane." Just take a constant map for example, or any continuous map $X \to \mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$... unless by "mapped to the plane" you mean "homeomorphic to the plane"

Comment: @leibnewtz Thank you, this is exactly the kind of feedback I'm looking for.

Comment: Also what's a finite plane?

Comment: @leibnewtz... however, do see the title of the question - parentheses.

Comment: What do you mean by "break" the topology? All the maps I mentioned are continuous, i.e. Preserve the topology

Comment: @leibnewtz One cannot do a [planar embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) of a sphere without changing its topology. Clear? That's what I mean by break... when viewed in a topological sense i.e. as a graph, you would need to somewhat disconnect the parts of the structure in order to perform a planar embedding.

Comment: So by "finite plane" you mean planar graph and by "map to" you mean embed. But a sphere is not a graph... it's a 2-dimensional CW complex or manifold

Comment: @leibnewtz Both of us know that a sphere can be approximated at whatever level of detail as a set of vertices and edges, i.e. _a graph_.

Comment: Maybe in computer graphics or something. If you want a precise answer you need to have a precise question. If you mean nonplanar graph, don't say sphere

Comment: @leibnewtz "Maybe in computer graphics or something" - so let's see, if it works in CG, that means it's a logical reality, meaning it is also a mathematical reality, no? Fair enough though, perhaps I am conflating terms somewhat. In any case... I appreciate your criticism, I have changed the question title and the wording somewhat, and I think I have my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

> We support topologies that are not homeomorphic to subsets of the
>   plane.

You can then list a few examples for your readers.

Comment: "The plane" presumably means the infinite plane? Hence, "subsets"?

Comment: Yes. This closed disk is homeomorphic to a subset of the plane but not to the plane.

Answer (score 0):

> X is needed because of the existence of *closed orientable 2-manifolds*, which have no planar embeddings homeomorphic to their original topology.

Comment: None of the spaces you mentioned are $3$-manifolds

Comment: You've answered your own question, so I suppose you have what you need. but a Moebius strip is not a three manifold, though the existence of three manifolds is sufficient for your purpose.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks, I've +1ed yours in any case. Yours is probably more accurate. I'll accept one or the other, soon.

Comment: @leibnewtz Thank you. Did I mean [2-manifold](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/2-manifolds)? I have changed the answer.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer I supported Ethan Bolker's comment above. But $2$- manifolds are too general (the plane itself is a $2$-manifold). Look up surfaces and compact subsurfaces

Comment: @leibnewtz See edit... better? I fear _surfaces_ may also be too ambiguous.

Comment: The word has an unambiguous definition: a surface is a compact $2$-manifold without boundary.